# Extension Method To Take A Dynamically Built Search Expression?

Tags: linq, extension-methods, dynamic-linq

I think we are basically looking for a extension method that could take in an IQueryable and return an IQueryable based on an entire query statement and not just the where statement.

Example of what we would like for a Search Method:

```
IRepository<Person> repository = new Repository<Person>();
var results = repository.GetQuery().Include("Names").Search([dynamic linq here]);
```

We currently have where we build a dynamic linq statement inside the where method

```
IRepository<Person> repository = new Repository<Person>();
var results = repository.GetQuery().Include("Names").Where([dynamic linq here]);
```

The problem with that approach is that we want to do include SelectMany and Select on the actual dynamic linq query. You cannot use the SelectMany inside a Where method unless you are actually going into sub properties of sub properties. We would like to do something like the following dynamic linq statement.

```
SelectMany("Names").Where("LastName.Contains(@0)", "Smith").Select("Person")
```

Answer (score 1):

We solved this issue without having to use a extension method. We were able to use a similar query that works inside a Where method.

So instead of...

```
SelectMany("Names").Where("LastName.Contains(@0)", "Smith").Select("Person")
```

We were able to get the same result with the following query that can be inside a Where method.

```
Where.("Names.Select(LastName).Contains(@0)", "Smith)
```

Then when just had to add a Contains Aggregate to the Dynamic Linq library.

http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html

The SelectMany had sent us off on a wild goose chase!

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout this nuget package: [NinjaNye.SearchExensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/)**

It enables you to do something like the following:

```
var repository = new Repository<Person>();
var results = repository.GetQuery().Search(p => p.LastName, "Smith");
```

Connected to sql this will produce something smilar to the following:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
       ... [other properties],
       [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName] 
FROM   [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  ([Extent1].[LastName] LIKE N'%Smith%')
```

The query is built using expression trees so the result is clean.
Check out the source code here: 
https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions/